# How to pay US F-1 Visa through credit or debit card?

Tags: visas, usa, f1-visas, student-visas

I am an international student from India enrolled in a US university. I have completed my Visa application and just have to pay the fees. However there is no option for credit or debit card payment. The payment options available are National Electronic Funds Transfer (NEFT), Mobile IMPS Payment and over the counter payment. I saw that credit/debit card payment option is available on the US Embassy sites of some other countries such as [New Zealand](https://www.ustraveldocs.com/nz/nz-niv-paymentinfo.asp#creditcard) and [Norway](https://www.ustraveldocs.com/no/no-niv-paymentinfo.asp) but not India. Is it not available for India? If so, any reason why?

Comment: Every country has different financial laws and those may make certain payment methods inconvenient, or difficult to use, or even impossible.

Comment: And because...national politics and different political choices.